# Переход между вкладками формы visual c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Создавая программу winforms, столкнулся с одной проблемой-не знаю как осуществить переход между вкладками в одной форме(через ссылку или кнопку). Между формами легко, но на вопрос о переходе между вкладками или в определенную вкладку другой формы ответа в интернете не нашел.

Comment: `tabControl.SelectedTab = yourtab` или `tabControl.SelectedIndex = 4`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте TabControl в панели элементов он есть.

Comment: Я его и использовал, но именно перехода между вкладками там нет.